# what is the difference between "notification area" (systray), "indicator plugin" (indicator) and "status notifier plugin" (statusnotifier)

Tags: xfce, indicator, xfce-panel

I got mildly annoyed that duplicate wi-fi and bluetooth icons were showing up in my panel, and tracked it down to the fact that they were showing up in both `systray` and `statusnotifier` plugins. Can someone explain the differences among them (and also `indicator`)?

- "notification area" (AKA: [systray](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/systray))
- "status notifier plugin" (AKA: [statusnotifier](https://goodies.xfce.org/projects/panel-plugins/xfce4-statusnotifier-plugin))
- "indicator plugin" (AKA: [indicator](https://goodies.xfce.org/projects/panel-plugins/xfce4-indicator-plugin))

So far I've read that `systray` has been around forever, that `statusnotifier` is newer and is somehow blessed by freedesktop (?) and that `indicator` was written to "address design concerns Canonical was having" ([here](https://askubuntu.com/a/147990/92714)).  Moreover, several things seem to have their own dedicated panel plugins, like "pulseaudio plugin" and "power manager plugin", which seem like they ought to work just fine as elements within either `systray` or `statusnotifier`.  Why is such a simple aspect of the UI so fractionated?  Is there any effort underway toward reunification into a single tray?  Is there some semantic distinction among these that I'm missing, that explains why it makes sense to have more than one?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

- *Notification area* is the classical system tray for X11. It's based on the [XEMBED protocol](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/systemtray-spec/systemtray-spec-0.2.html). Due to being X11-specific, it's considered obsolete by many progressive minds who think that Wayland is the future.
- *Status notifier* implements the StatusNotifierHost part of the [StatusNotifierItem specification](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/StatusNotifierItem/). This mechanism is based on D-BUS, which is independent of the windowing system, so it's compatible with X11, Wayland etc..
- *Indicator* is a plugin showing status of various messaging apps. This one is not a system tray implementation. It's a specialized type of info display & control. There is some documentation on this system on an [Ubuntu Wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MessagingMenu/). From what I could gather there, it uses [libindicate](https://launchpad.net/libindicate) to communicate with the applications, and this library, in its turn, uses D-BUS for message passing.

Of these three, the first two seem to be alternatives, so you could use one of them. But in my experience, *Notification area* shows more complete set of icons from different applications. In particular, if you have some programs which use XEMBED-based tray icons, you *need* this plugin. See also: ["Where are my systray icons?"](https://blog.martin-graesslin.com/blog/2014/06/where-are-my-systray-icons/) blog post by a KDE developer (from 2014, when this mess appeared).

The *Indicator* plugin is needed if you want to have a single place to access messaging apps like e.g. Pidgin or Evolution. By default, in Ubuntu messengers like Pidgin don't show their real tray icons, relying on the presence of the *Indicator*. If you remove *Indicator* from the panel, be sure to enable these tray icons in the settings of each messenger you're using.

Comment: I'll stick with Notification area (systray) for a while because NetworkManager Applet doesn't show itself in the Status Notifier. And also it's the most up-to-date package (in 2019).

Comment: Earlier, I too used to face the same issue as reported by @dmnc. But it seems that in xfce4.14 (Xubuntu 20.04), this issue has been rectified and tray icons are properly shown in **status notifier**. Furthermore, this is able to render icons from the selected icon theme (which is not the case with **notification area**).

Answer (score 0):

"Notification Area" shows some notifications which are not shown in "Status Notifier" and "Indicator", e.g. network connection. So I have to enable it.

Then, comparing the "Status Notifier" and "Indicator":
at least one of my apps (Slack) shows up ONLY in Indicator. All other apps show up in both of them.
So, I have to use the "Indicator plugin" for this reason.

Enabling the "Status Notifier" just duplicates most (but not all) of the notifications, so I disabled it.

It's confusing to have three of them (it's like in addition to the "windows" on your desktop you also have some "doors" and even "holes").

Comment: To add, (1) this is mentioned in ["known issues"](https://docs.xfce.org/panel-plugins/xfce4-statusnotifier-plugin/start#known_issues) and (2) the plugin itself is marked as deprecated as of xfce 4.15+